# Is negative_mean_squared greater the more accuracy or less computes to more accuracy?

Tags: scikit-learn, gridsearchcv, mean-square-error

-0.567 
-4.235
Which of the above negative_mean_squared error value computes to more accuracy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Higher the value better it is. So in your case `-0.567` is better. A per the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html) sklearn scoring functions maintain the following convention **higher return values are better than lower return values**.  But when you look at `mean_squared_error` or for that matter even `mean_absolute_error` lower the value better it is. So they just flip the sign of the value to make sure it follows the convention. For your example, `-0.567` results in a `mean_squared_error` of just `0.567` whereas, `-4.235` has a `mean_squared_error` of `4.235` which is much higher than the former.